# Why we can't conserve light?

Tags: visible-light

All I made up in my mind about light beeing a wave  traveling at vertain speed, made me thing of it like something we could store in tehory.

So I would assume if I had a box where the inside is made up completly with mirrors, when sending light in and closing the box, this light would keep traveling inside the box, beeing reflected by the mirrors untill we release it again.

But afaik this isn't the way it is.
So how does it come?
Why isn't light working this way?

Comment: Mirrors have two big issues - aiming, and that they aren't perfectly reflective. 99.999% doesn't sound bad until you realize the light will make billions of bounces each second.

Comment: @JanDvorak: So my idea isn't incorrect, and would even turn out to be correct if we had 100% reflective mirrors?

Comment: @JanDvorak: What happens to the absorbed light? Is it by some means nbeutralized?

Comment: What happens to light that hits a black surface?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I know that this is the same answer but technically "it dissapears" is all I know.

Comment: @Zaibis Turns into heat, mostly.